write system call keeps being called
I am facing strange issue. I designed the kernel driver which implements open, close and write. When I perform
echo something > /dev/mydevice

the write call of the driver is being called in loop with the same data. Terminal is busy, breakable using ^C (and then of course looping stops).
At the end of write function I return 0.
The cause and solution must be trivial, but I do not see it.

"At the end of write function I return 0" - you should return the number of bytes processed: Writing to Linux device driver causes infinite loop.

@Tsyvarev great thanks for your insight. That surely solved the issue. So I was not alone thinking that write returns error or success. If one would start writing user space app to access the driver (instead of using echo) then this mistake would surface quickly.
